# Stored Procedure Error (column ambiguously defined)

Tags: oracle, join, stored-procedures, plsql

Getting the following error for this line Create a stored procedure that takes as its argument as  industryid

```
 CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE businesses (industryid INDUSTRY.INDUSTRYID%TYPE) AS
    
CURSOR businessloop IS
select tx.UNIONTITLE,b.ABNNUMBER,b.BUSINESSNAME
from business b INNER JOIN business_industry bi
on
b.ABNNUMBER = bi.ABNNUMBER
INNER JOIN industry ind
on
bi.INDUSTRYID = ind.INDUSTRYID
INNER JOIN trade_union tx
on 
ind.UNIONID = tx.UNIONID
where 
INDUSTRY.INDUSTRYID = industryid;

BEGIN

FOR ptr IN businessloop LOOP
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(ptr.UNIONTITLE);
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(ptr.ABNNUMBER);
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(ptr.BUSINESSNAME);
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('---------------------------');
END LOOP;

end businesses;
/
Execute businesses(6);
```

my output looks like this

```
Errors: PROCEDURE BUSINESSES
Line/Col: 5/1 PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
Line/Col: 16/23 PL/SQL: ORA-00918: column ambiguously defined
Line/Col: 26/1 PL/SQL: Statement ignored
Line/Col: 26/22 PLS-00364: loop index variable 'PTR' use is invalid
Line/Col: 27/1 PL/SQL: Statement ignored
Line/Col: 27/22 PLS-00364: loop index variable 'PTR' use is invalid
Line/Col: 28/1 PL/SQL: Statement ignored
Line/Col: 28/22 PLS-00364: loop index variable 'PTR' use is invalid

ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PLS-00905: object SQL_PQETEGYQDKCHNVXHUMIWRPLSE.BUSINESSES is invalid
```

I think error comes with this line

```
INDUSTRY.INDUSTRYID = industryid;
```

Comment: *I think error comes with this line* You're probably right. Rename procedure's parameter and eliminate names interference.

Comment: thanks, man that's the reason, @Akina

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer

```
 CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE businesses (industryidx INDUSTRY.INDUSTRYID%TYPE) AS
    
CURSOR businessloop IS
select tx.UNIONTITLE,b.ABNNUMBER,b.BUSINESSNAME
from business b INNER JOIN business_industry bi
on
b.ABNNUMBER = bi.ABNNUMBER
INNER JOIN industry ind
on
bi.INDUSTRYID = ind.INDUSTRYID
INNER JOIN trade_union tx
on 
ind.UNIONID = tx.UNIONID
where 
ind.INDUSTRYID = industryidx;

BEGIN

FOR ptr IN businessloop LOOP
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(ptr.UNIONTITLE);
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(ptr.ABNNUMBER);
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(ptr.BUSINESSNAME);
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('---------------------------');
END LOOP;

end businesses;
/
Execute businesses(6);
```

Answer (score 1):

Answered in comments:

> *I think error comes with this line* You're probably right. Rename procedure's parameter and eliminate names interference. – Akina 2 hours ago

> thanks, man that's the reason, @Akina – sandun wijerathne Jerry 2 hours ago